# PHP запутывание строки (кириллица)

Tags: php, массивы, строки, шифрование, кириллица

Есть случайная строка:

```
$string = "Если указан необязательный аргумент split_length, возвращаемый массив будет содержать части исходной строки длиной split_length каждая, иначе каждый элемент будет содержать один символ.";
```

По необходимости мне надо сделать так, что бы другие не смогли её прочитать. Для этого я использую функцию:

```
function mbStringToArray($string){ 
    $strlen = mb_strlen($string); 
    while($strlen) { 
        $array[] = mb_substr($string,0,1,"UTF-8"); 
        $string = mb_substr($string,1,$strlen,"UTF-8"); 
        $strlen = mb_strlen($string); 
    } 
    return $array; 
}

$arr = mbStringToArray($string);
shuffle($arr);
$string = implode('', $arr);
```

Но проблема в том, что если передавать строку по одному символу, то и итоге можно понять написанное.

Потому суть задачи - это не просто пересортировать буквы в строке в любом порядке, но еще и заменить эти буквы на другие. При этом можна не мешать через shuffle массив символов, а специальным алгоритмом перемешать их. Что бы потом, если понадобится, розшифровать запутаную строку и получить исходный текст.

Comment: Что значит "по одному символу"? И почему нельзя использовать хотя бы банальное "xor шифрование" сочетая с ROT13 и base64? Или один из многочисленных вариантов шифрования строк? То что кириллица - ну так прогоните его до шифрования через baseXX

Comment: ну это чат и xor не красиво отображается. Пример: :3391=�_aY . А хотелось бы видеть нормальные символы. А если до шифрование прогнать строку через baseXX, то получается еще хуже.

Comment: Прогоните basexx после xor. И что значит отображается? Вы шифруете для того, чтобы никто не смотрел или для чего?. Единственная _потенциальная_ проблема - кракозяблы и кодировка, но от нее спасает baseXX на выходе.

Comment: текст видно будет, но надо, что бы не прочитали. При этом он должен "красиво" отобразится, т.е. русс. буквами. Ну как в описании задачи. И как раз кракозяблы и кодировка - это ПРОБЛЕМА.

Comment: Замените одни русские буквы на другие по алгоритму ROT13, только двигайте не на 13 позиций по алфавиту, а по некому ключу, который определит на сколько позиций двигать. Получите абракадабру.

Comment: Преобразование ROT13 заключается в простом сдвиге каждой латинской буквы на 13 позиций в алфавите, остальные символы не изменяются. Ключевое слово - "латинской".

Comment: или может есть алгоритм, что бы как-то русские символы перевести на анг., при этом анг. оставить не трогать. Ну а потом уже можно ROT13. Главное что бы красиво смотрелось, т.е. не иероглифы.

Comment: 1 Кто запрещает забить массив-словарь из 33 русских букв и двигать по нему? Получаем индекс текущей буквы - узнаем на сколько хотим сдвинуть (ключ) и вычисляем новый индекс с буквой. ROT это сам подход к замене одних букв другими. 2 в латиницу тоже легко переводится (не знаю зачем) - просто массив "буква -> транскрипция"

Comment: идея с переводом рус. букв на анг. очень интересна. При этом могу указать даже не транскрипцию, а 'й' => 'q' или еще как-то запутать. Ну а потом уже через ROT13. Спасибо большое за идею над алгоритмом.